# How can I put a heading and a paragraph on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get a `<p>` and an `<h4>` element on the same line (inside of a card).

I've tried the following:

```css
.where,
.location {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #acdd1b;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 150px;
}

.when,
.dates {
  display: inline;
  color: #ddd01b;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p class="where">Where:</p>
<h4 class="location">Gili Air - Lombok, Indonesia</h4>
<p class="dates">When:</p>
<p class="dates">01-01-'24 - 01-03-'24</p>
```

This didn't work. They are still on two separate lines (although the inline-block leaves less of a gap).

After I tried to put them into a `<div class="line">`, as someone had suggested in earlier posts, and if I then set the CSS to `.line {display: flex; align-items: center;}`, it works, but it becomes really ugly as the heading sits higher than the paragraph.

How can I fix this? Or isn't there another way than to style the `.line` and pull up the heading tag manually?

Comment: Everything appears on one line here

Comment: It's already doing what it expected, I think your code has some extra CSS that is causing the issue for you, if it's open source could you show the whole code?

Comment: This seems like a misuse of both [paragraph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) and [heading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#usage_notes) elements. Please be aware of the semantic meaning of each and use them accordingly. Use basic structural elements for positioning.

Answer (score 2):

You may do like this. Here I moved the `<span>` tag into the `<p>` tag. And styled the `.location` with `font-weight: 600;` so that it looks bold like you did with `<h4>` tag

```css
.location{
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<p class="where"> Where: <span class="location"> Gili Air - Lombok, Indonesia </span> </p>
```

Comment: Questions do not belong in answers, even if rhetorical. [Stack Overflow is *** *** ***not*** *** *** a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828). Please [make](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77616498/edit) the answer affirmative. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, now is it okay?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `<strong></strong>` tag inside of your `<p>` tag to create a bold section. You can also style it with CSS to be more like a header if you wanted to.

Comment: Hi Ansh, I tried re-styling the header to look like a paragraph, it wasn't about it being bold. The dates and location were the ones I'd like them to find the site on. Just saw someone closed the question, thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `display: flex;` property on their container. (And set the width of your card container.)

```css
.your-container-name {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Hi Farnoud, 

That's exactly what my third attempt was! Even set the size and font-weight the same. But the header still hangs a bit higher than the paragraph. 

I was hoping there was an easier solution than manually pulling the header down.

Comment: have you tried vertical-align?Let's test this. using the vertical-align: middle; property to ensure vertical alignment within the flex container.

Comment: That somehow seems to pull it even higher up. Let me see if I can find a way to paste the whole code.